# How do I retrieve a DNS resource record by hostname

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to retrieve a SoftLayer DNS resource record by hostname.

I have tried 2 different methods.

First URL is

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[domain]&objectFilter={"resourceRecord":{"host":{"operation":"dsn-p01"}}}
```

This returns RC 500, MSG "Internal Server Error", CONTENT '{"error":"Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_ResourceRecord::getObject)","code":"SoftLayer_Exception"}'

My suspicion is that it is looking for teh DNS resource record ID, which I don't have.

My next attempt was using this URL:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/getByDomainName/dsn-xxx.com.json?objectMask=mask[resourceRecordCount;resourceRecords]&objectFilter={"resourceRecords":{"host":{"operation":"dsn-p01"}}}
```

This returns the domain records and all the resourceRecords associated with the domain.

How can I retrieve a single SoftLayer resourceRecord by hostname?

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getDomains?objectMask=mask[resourceRecords]&objectFilter={   "domains": {     "resourceRecords": {       "host": {         "operation": "myHostTest"       }     }   } }

Method: GET
```

#### EDIT:

Also if you know the `dns_domain_id`, you can try the following:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/[dns_domain_id]/getResourceRecords?objectFilter={"resourceRecords":{"host":{"operation": "myHostTest"}}}

Method: GET
```

Comment: I tried teh suggested example URL:  'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getDomains?objectMask=mask[resourceRecords]&objectFilter={"domains":{"resourceRecords":{"host":{"operation":"dsn-p01"}}}}'

Comment: I tried the suggested example URL:  'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getDomains?objectMask=mask[resourceRecords]&objectFilter={"domains":{"resourceRecords":{"host":{"operation":"dsn-p01"}}}}'   This returned all resourceRecords.  I also tried to search for a resourceRecord tye only with URL: 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getDomains?objectMask=mask[resourceRecords]&objectFilter={"domains":{"resourceRecords":{"type":{"operation":"a"}}}}'  This returned all resourceRecords also

Comment: Well, as we are using `getDomains`, the response will be display the matched domain with all its content data. If you know the `dns_domain_id`, we can use [SoftLayer_Dns_Domain::getResourceRecords](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/getResourceRecords). In this case, the response will list only the filtered `resource Record`. I updated the answer, please see `EDIT` section.

Comment: That worked,  I did a SoftLayer_Dns_Domain/getByDomainName to get the domain id and then issued your example.  I may add another operation to only get type a resourceRecords.   Thank you.